# Creating an app variant in a firebase unity project

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, apk, android-contentprovider

I have en existing app (e.g `com.company.app1`)made in Unity, that occasionally pulls content from firebase in the live environment (after being built).

Now I am trying to make a second build, with a different project id (`com.company.app2`). This second build does not use firebase after being built - it loads data from firebase before being built, and therefore already contains the needed data.

I have added `com.company.app2` as a second android app in my firebase configuration, but when trying to install the resulting `app2.apk` there's a clash between it and the existing installed `app1.apk`.

Below is the error Unity is showing when I press it's "Build and Run" button.

```
stderr[
adb: failed to install C:\Users\*\*\*\*\app2.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER: Scanning Failed.: 
Can't install because provider name 
com.company.app1.firebaseinitprovider (in package com.company.app2) is already used by com.company.app1]
]
```

My question is, how can I change the provider name in `app2` so both `app1` and `app2` can coexist on the same device?

(I need to interface with firebase shortly before building, so I can't just remove the SDK).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I ended up just removing the SDK, that works.

Sorry to anyone who has some similar problem.